# Better way of enforcing this template?

Tags: c++

Currently, I have a function template like this that converts a `vector` into a `string` (just a natural string, separating the elements with a comma):

```
//the type T must be passable into std::to_string
template<typename T>
std::string vec_to_str(const std::vector<T> &vec);
```

As you can see, this is only meant for vectors whose elements can be passed into the built-in `std::to_string` function (such as `int`, `double`, etc.)

Is it considered a good practice to document with comments the allowed `T`? If not, what should I do? Is it possible to enforce this in a better way?

Comment: Of course, you can even choose to document with comments AND enforce with a SFINAE technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `std::to_string` is a C++11 feature, I guess you might be open to a C++11 solution. In this particular case, you can use the trailing return type in a sfinae manner:

```
template <typename T>
auto vec_to_str(const std::vector<T>& vec) -> decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()));
```

which would fail to substitute (and eliminate that overload) if the value-type does not work for `to_string`. But still, that's not necessarily the most eye-pleasing way to document and enforce the rule. There is probably a pre-C++11 version of the above Sfinae trick too, but it won't be any prettier.

In general, I would say that it's fine to simply document it in the comments (possibly with a doxygen tag, like `\tparam`). You could use a concept-check mechanism, in the style of Boost.Concept-Check if you want.

As a side note, for this specific case, I might recommend that you rely on the `std::ostream` `operator <<` instead of the `to_string` function, since it is more likely that custom types (e.g., a 2D vector or something) will be equipped with an overload for outputting to a stream.

Answer (score 4):

With `static_assert` and some expression SFINAE, you can have a nice compile time error message:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto allowed(int) -> decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()), bool())
{
    return true;
}

template<typename>
constexpr bool allowed(...)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
std::string vec_to_str(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    static_assert(allowed<T>(0), "Invalid value type.");
    return "";
}

struct foo {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v_int;
    vec_to_str(v_int);

    std::vector<foo> v_double;
    vec_to_str(v_double);       // static_assert fires here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until [concepts](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/WG2.8/28/slides/bjarne.pdf) arrive, you can use `decltype` with an anonymous type parameter:

```
template<typename T,
  typename = decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
std::string vec_to_str(const std::vector<T> &vec);
```